# This JAVA code isn't generating CSV file

Tags: java, mysql, csv, netbeans, export-to-csv

I have this java code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Propietaria {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   DBase db = new DBase();
   Connection conn = db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/propietaria","root","");

   if (args.length != 1) {
     System.out.println("Usage: java automateExport [outputfile path] ");
     return;
   }
   db.exportData(conn,args[0]);
 }

}

class DBase {
 public DBase() {
 }

 public Connection connect(String db_connect_str,
 String db_userid, String db_password) {
   Connection conn;
   String filename;
   filename = "payroll.csv";
   try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_str, db_userid, db_password);

   } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     conn = null;
   }
   return conn;
 }

 public void exportData(Connection conn,String filename) {
   Statement stmt;
   String query;
   try {
     stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

     //For comma separated file
    query = "SELECT id, numero_cuenta, nombre_empleado, sueldo, horas_trabajadas, horas_vacaciones, sueldo" +
     "INTO OUTFILE 'probando/payroll.csv'" +
     "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " +
     "FROM nomina";
    stmt.executeQuery(query);

   } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     stmt = null;
   }
 }
};
```

I am trying to generate a CSV of data that come from a table called `nomina` that is at `propietaria` database.

When I execute the query (MySQL) this create me the file, but that is only at SQLyog. When I run this code, the console send me the message "Usage: java automateExport [outputfile path]"

This is the structure of the nomina table:

```
 id  numero_cuenta  nombre_empleado  horas_trabajadas  horas_vacaciones  sueldo  
------  -------------  ---------------  ----------------  ----------------  --------
  1001      712332889  Tony Smith                     50                 5  40.00   
  1002      785445566  David Jones                    40                 0  10.00   
  1003      454544545  Denise Smith                   35                 3  20.00   
  1008      445565545  Sebastien Motte                50                 5  0.00    
  1011      122154555  Isabelle Scemla                40                 0  40.00   
  1012      154668544  David Bristol                  40                 5  40.00   
  1025      225468255  Anne Weiler                    36                 0  20.00   
  1032      336566585  Luka Abrus                     40                 5  0.00    
  1049      525556556  David Ludwig                   40                 1  0.00    
  1050      525556557  Tony Smith                     50                 5  40.00   
  1051      525556558  David Jones                    40                 0  10.00   
  1052      525556559  Denise Smith                   35                 3  20.00
```

Have more records, but is to show you an example.

EDIT: I forgot to say that when I run the query in SQLyog this create me the CSV file at: xamp>mysql>data>probando(folder that I created)>payroll.csv

Maybe Java create me this file at another place?

Comment: So, _how_ are you running the code? Are you passing the mandatory argument (output path) in?

Comment: @MickMnemonic well, exactly in the code is not where I have the output path of the file. I have the output path in the query. Will it be wrong? I edited the post with a little more information.

Comment: The error message seems clear to me. You need to pass the output path as an argument to the Java application, e.g. executing it with `java Propietaria "C:\temp"`

Comment: I do not see code that actually processes data from database. `stmt.executeQuery(query);` executes query and provides result as `ResultSet` object but nothing is done with that `ResultSet` after that.